# Sorted list out of memory in Unity 3d?

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, out-of-memory, sortedlist

Editor is saying error: Out of memory.  Hi guys, I am learning about the sorted list. The method PrintMessage runs every second. And the Add funtion is causing the bug. Would you be able to tell what's wrong based on the code blow? Thank you.

```
void PrintMessage(GameObject gameObject) {
    Target newTarget = new Target(gameObject, transform.position);
    targets.Add(newTarget);
    print(targets[targets.Count-1].Distance.ToString());
}

public void Add(T item)
{
    int num;
    // add your implementation below
    if (items.Count != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            num = item.CompareTo(items[i]);
            if (num >= 0)
            {
                tempList.AddRange(items.GetRange(i, items.Count - i));
                items.RemoveRange(i, items.Count - i);
                items.Add(item);
                items.AddRange(tempList);
                tempList.Clear();
                continue;
            }
        }
        items.Add(item);
    }
    else
    {
        items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `targets.Add(newTarget)` anyway? The method exists to "print an object", so it shouldn't need to add the object to a list.

Comment: well it will add a new target object to the sorted list anyway. And finally the closest object distance will be printed.

Comment: You are iterating over all items, and add each one to "items" in the loop. Your growth is therefore exponential. Are you sure you want that inner `items.Add(item)` call ? (inside the for-loop) ?

Comment: instead of `continue;` you probably want to do `return;` .. otherwise you call `items.Add` at least twice or maybe even more often in the `for` loop ...

Comment: I see. Thanks guys. return is what I want to do. I thought continue can work the same.

Comment: You guys are awesome!! It fixed!!

Comment: I have a question again. The num of target that will be generated is up to 20. A list cannot hold that few content? When I say continue. Doesnt that mean we all done with this turn of the loop. Lets do the next turn. Why will it call it many times. Even the item.add isnt inside the for loop.

Comment: A list can have no things in it to many many many many things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that inside of

```c#
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    ...
    items.Add(item);
    ...
}
```

you continously add more and more items. So every iteration of the loop the `items.Count` will be +1 item bigger => the exit condition `i >= items.Count` will never be met.

→ **Never** change the List count while iterating over the same list!

Reason for that in the end is you're using `continue`(go to the next iteration) .. it makes no sense there since at this point anyway the next iteration would start.

You probably ment `break`(interrupt the loop) or even `return` since anyway right after the loop again you call `items.Add(item)` ...

---

You probably rather want to use [`List<T>.Insert(int index, T item)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert)

```c#
public void Add(T item)
{
    int newIndex = 0;

    // You don't need an additional if-else
    // since this loop is anyway never executed
    // if (items.Count == 0)
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        num = item.CompareTo(items[i]);
        if (num >= 0)
        {
            // we want to add the new item AFTER
            // the item we compared it to
            newIndex = i+1;
            return;
        }
    }

    // Inserts the item at index newIndex
    // if newIndex == items.Count this equals Add
    items.Insert(newIndex, item);
}
```

---

**Note that this actually already exists!**

It is called [`SortedSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1)

Comment: I was using the items.Insert before but the Insert was also inside of the for loop lol. Thank you for your reply and the new solution. It makes me love the website! What lovely people hanging out here. Problems got solved so fast!!!

Comment: see my latest update .. did you checkout `SortedSet<T>` .. it is basically exactly what you are trying to implement ;)

Comment: Sure I will check. Thank you again!! :)